# Is this a sleight of hand or a video edit?

Tags: knot-theory, puzzle

In another question someone linked to [this video](http://www.math.toronto.edu/~drorbn/Gallery/KnottedObjects/WaistbandTrick/index.html) where the lady ties a knot in a seemingly impossible manner.
What I don't understand is how the end sticking out beyond her right hand gets longer as she pulls through (seems that if it's to change it should get shorter). This suggests to me that there is some footage cut out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sleight of hand!  I learned to do this by watching the video - there is a moment when you let go of the end of the rope and grab another part.  Your observation is telling you which end to let go of, when to let go, and where to grab.

Comment: Neat trick.. I must work on this!

Comment: I'd vote for you Sam but I don't have a good enough reputation, sorry.

Comment: Ha! I learned this trick way back in the late 70s or early 80s but managed to forget it, much to my chagrin. Now I should be able to relearn it.

Comment: Voted for you now!